# After pushng my Rails up to Openshift I get error: "Could not find rake-10.5.0 in any of the sources"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openshift

I'm trying to set up my Rails app with Mongo.
After setting the code as described in the Advanced section [here](https://blog.openshift.com/converting-an-existing-rails-app-to-run-on-openshift/)

I added the mirror source to Gemfile like this

```
ruby "2.0.0"

source 'http://mirror1.prod.rhcloud.com/mirror/ruby/'
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.5'
...
```

And to Gemfile.lock

```
GEM
  remote: http://mirror1.prod.rhcloud.com/mirror/ruby/
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (4.2.5)
```

I tried to push the code and getting:

```
remote: /opt/rh/ror40/root/usr/share/gems/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92:in `block in materialize': Could not find rake-10.5.0 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
remote:     from /opt/rh/ror40/root/usr/share/gems/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `map!'
remote:     from /opt/rh/ror40/root/usr/share/gems/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `materialize'
remote:     from /opt/rh/ror40/root/usr/share/gems/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:114:in `specs'
remote:     from /opt/rh/ror40/root/usr/share/gems/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:159:in `specs_for'
remote:     from /opt/rh/ror40/root/usr/share/gems/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:148:in `requested_specs'
remote:     from /opt/rh/ror40/root/usr/share/gems/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/environment.rb:18:in `requested_specs'
remote:     from /opt/rh/ror40/root/usr/share/gems/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:13:in `setup'
remote:     from /opt/rh/ror40/root/usr/share/gems/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:120:in `setup'
remote:     from /opt/rh/ror40/root/usr/share/gems/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/setup.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
remote:     from /opt/rh/ruby200/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
remote:     from /opt/rh/ruby200/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
remote: Compilation of assets is disabled or assets not detected.
```

Comment: Got any workaround ? I'm also facing the same issue.

Comment: @NinjaBoy added answer. Make sure the gems install when you do `git push`

Comment: Thanks, I eventually figured it out. But I'm having an issue with passenger now :-(

Answer (score 0):

I removed the mirror sources and also removed Puma.
Then encountered `You have already activated rack 1.5.2, but your Gemfile requires rack 1.6.4. Using bundle exec may solve this. (Gem::LoadError)` and followed the instructions [here](http://www.gerardcondon.com/blog/2015/06/15/upgrading-to-rails-4-dot-2-on-openshift/)